# Create a cleaned up contact object of an array of contact data

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have an array with objects like this (simplefied version, actual array has much more data):

```
[
    {
        id: '1',
        name: 'Joe',
        description: 'Student',
        locations: [ {
            type: 'home',
            value: '123'
        } ]
    },
    {
        id: '1',
        name: 'Joe',
        description: 'Farmer',
        locations: [ {
            type: 'home',
            value: '456'
        } ]
    },
    {
        id: '1',
        name: 'Joe',
        description: '',
        locations: [ {
            type: 'home',
            value: '123'
        } ]
    }
]
```

**How can I use javascript (lodash) to create the following? :**

```
{
    id: '1',
    name: 'Joe',
    description: 'Farmer',
    locations: [ {
        type: 'home',
        value: '123'
    }, {
        type: 'home',
        value: '456'
    } ]
}
```

The goal is to create a cleaned up contact object of an array of contact data. So it needs to replace single attributes like name and description in case they are empty. And push objects like location in case its not found in de locations array. I did get some results using _.merge, problem is that merge always overrides with last value and doesnt push new values, so result would be something like this:

```
{
    id: '1',
    name: 'Joe',
    description: '',
    locations: [ {
        type: 'home',
        value: '123'
    }]
}
```

Comment: How do you determine that description should be 'Farmer', not 'Student'?

Comment: that's a sacrifice I need to make, there is no way to indicate priority.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of unsolved questions regarding how to handle conflicts.

- Should the last property override the previous one? do you want to join only by `locations`?
- Is the joining done only by `id`?
- How do you determine uniqueness in `locations`? Is it by `type`, `value` or a combination?

Once you have an answer to these questions, you can use something like this:

```
// this will get you the items (from server/localstorage/whatever)
var items = getItems();

// group items by id (assuming that's our grouping denominator
var groupedItems = _.groupBy(items, 'id');

// then iterate through each item in group, and reduce them
var results = _.map(_.values(groupdItems), function(item) {
    var reduced =  _.reduce(item, function(result, num, key) {
        if (key === 'locations') {
           // join everything together, we'll unique them later
           result.locations = (result.locations || []).concat(num || []);  
        }
        else {
           // override all previous values for this key.
           // change this to improve behavior
           result[key] = num;
        }
        return result;
    }, {});
    // reduce locations to unique locations only
    // currently implemented by using JSON.stringified but could easily change
    reduced.locations = _.uniq(reduced.locations, function(loc) {
      return JSON.stringify(loc);
    });
    return reduced;
});

// results should now contains the transformed items.
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this should be enough:

```
function customMerge(obj1, obj2) {
    for(var i in obj2) {
        if(typeof(obj1[i]) === 'object' && obj1[i].push) {
            for(var j in obj2[i]) {
                obj1[i].push(obj2[i][j]);
            }
            obj1[i] = arrayUnique(obj1[i]);
        } else {
            obj1[i] = obj2[i];
        }
    }
}

function arrayUnique(list, byKey) {
    var newList = [];
    var map = {};
    for(var i in list) {
        var data = list[i];
        var id = list[i].id || JSON.stringify(data);
        if(typeof(map[id]) === 'undefined') {
            map[id] = data;
        } else {
            customMerge(map[id], data);
        }
    }
    for(var i in map) {
        newList.push(map[i]);
    }
    return newList;
}
```

This returns what you're expecting:

```
arrayUnique([
    {
        id: '1',
        name: 'Joe',
        description: 'Student',
        locations: [ {
            type: 'home',
            value: '123'
        } ]
    },
    {
        id: '1',
        name: 'Joe',
        description: 'Farmer',
        locations: [ {
            type: 'home',
            value: '456'
        } ]
    },
    {
        id: '1',
        name: 'Joe',
        description: '',
        locations: [ {
            type: 'home',
            value: '123'
        } ]
    }
])
```